# Enabling zlib on a PHP 5.2 server for my PHP site

Tags: php, .htaccess, zlib

I am trying to generate Zip through my site to download multiple files. Unfortunately, I receive this error:

> Abort pclzip.lib.php : Missing zlib extensions

The problem is that I don't have access to php.ini and I was hoping to install zlib through htaccess. (I am assuming that zlib is missing, that's why it's doing so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. PHP extensions must be loaded at server startup in php.ini.

Find another hosting provider that has the zlib extension loaded, or which will allow you to load it yourself. You need one anyways -- PHP 5.2 is about ten years old, and has been unsupported by the PHP development team for the last five years.